# PostgreSQL delete rows that outer join from multiple tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sql-delete, outer-join

I am trying to delete rows from table where theire IDs doesnt exist in other 2 tales. on PostgreSQL :

table A :

| idB | idC | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | Three |
| 2 | 5 | Three |
| 3 | 6 | Three |

table B :

| idB | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Two | Three |
| 7 | Two | Three |

table C :

| idC | name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Two | Three |
| 5 | Two | Three |
| 6 | Two | Three |

final table A :

| idB | idC | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 6 | Three |

---

first row of table A should be deleted because idC = 4 doesnt exist in table C
Second row of table A should be deleted because idB = 2 doesnt exist in table B
Third row of table A should be kept idB = 3 exists in table B and  idC = 6 exists in table C

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `not exists`:

```
delete from tableA a
    where not exists (select 1 from tableB b where b.idB = a.idB) or
          not exists (select 1 from tableC c where c.idC = a.idC);
```

Answer (score 1):

here is how you can do it:

```
with tt as (
  select a.* from tableA a
  left join tableB b on a.idb =b.idb
  left join tableC c on a.idC = c.idc
  where b.idb is null or c.idc is null
)
delete from tableA a
using tt 
where a.idB = tt.idB
and a.idC = tt.idC
```